# R Convert list to lowercase

Tags: r, list, lowercase

Var1 is a list:

```
var1 <- list(c("Parts of a Day", "Time in Astronomy", "Star"),  c("Tree Tall", "Pine Tree"))
```

How to convert all the characters to lowercase? The desired answer is the following list:

```
var1 <- list(c("parts of a day", "time in astronomy", "star"),  c("tree tall", "pine tree"))
```

I used

```
as.list(tolower(var1))
```

But it gives the following answer with unwanted \

```
[[1]]
[1] "c(\"parts of a day\", \"time in astronomy\", \"star\")"

[[2]]
[1] "c(\"tree tall\", \"pine tree\")"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should use `lapply` to lower case each character vector in your list

```
lapply(var1, tolower)

# [[1]]
# [1] "parts of a day"    "time in astronomy" "star"             
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "tree tall" "pine tree"
```

otherwise `tolower` does `as.character()` on your entire list which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gsub`

```
gsub("/", "", var1)
as.list(tolower(var1))
```

this will remove all your / out of your variable.